# I need help adding an array to a vector in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, vector

I'm following along with the OpenGL Super Bible 5th edition, and they define a vector(vector as in math) as

```
typedef float   M3DVector3f[3];
```

I'm trying to add an instance of this to an std::vector(the 're sizable array' in c++), however I keep getting an error saying:

```
array initialization needs curly braces
```

[Full Error](http://pastebin.com/HDZYmyNa)

The way I defined the std::vector and the way I'm adding to it is:

```
std::vector<M3DVector3f> vertices;

float vertex[3];
sscanf_s(line.c_str(), "%*s %f %f %f", &vertex[0], &vertex[1], &vertex[2]);

M3DVector3f v = {vertex[0], vertex[1], vertex[3]};

vertices.push_back(v);
```

I've gathered that the problem is with the vertices.push_back(v) call, because I don't get an error when I comment that out. Could someone explain to me and help me figure out why it won't let me add this vector to my vector?

Comment: +1 for nicely formatted question

Comment: I just want to say thanks to everyone to who helped me. I took GMan's advice and created a new class for all of my Vectors. This worked out a lot better because it let me overload operators so now my code looks all clean and tidy. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays cannot be (directly) copied or assigned, and standard containers requires types to be copyable and assignable.

However, you can (and probably should) do this instead:

```
struct M3DVector3f // a basic vector class
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
```

Which *is* copyable and just as usable.

Comment: It's also more readable as it shows what each component represents.

Comment: why doesn't the implementation throw error while declaring 'vertices' instead, if it does not meet the requirements of the container?

Comment: @Chubsdad: Because it doesn't have to. The use of these requirements doesn't occur until the instantiation of the functions that use it. (This is even more important in C++0x, where element requirements are applied on a per-function basis.)

Comment: @GMan: From a design point of view, I would love to see the declaration itself fail rather than pushing the surprise element to the actual point of usage, especially when almost nothing can be done with such a declaration e.g. for some trivial functions like size(). Looks like it is a limitation of the language mechanism

Comment: @Chubsdad: It could be done (by inheriting from a mixin class that does a variety of static_assert's and concept checks), but again after C++03 such behavior would be wrong.

Comment: I actually had it like this at first and it worked, however I started using the vertices for adding and subtracting, and the guys who made the OpenGL Super Bible gave me a 3d math library with the M3DVector3f already defined, and they made functions for adding/subtracting and things like dot products and whatnot. It seemed dumb to remake those functions, so I decided to switch to using their M3DVector3f so I could use their library. Is there no way that I can force this to work somehow? If not, could someone recommend a good 3D math library I can use so I don't need to make my own?

Comment: @user: Nope, there's no way to get it to work with arrays directly, you either need to stuff them in a struct or do something else. I don't know any simple math libraries off-hand, but honestly I would recommend writing one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, vertex[3] above should be vertex[2] as vertex[3] lies outside the upper bound of the array.  However, that is not the crux of the issue here.  The template instantiation of vector is being done with an array type.  There is no default copy constructor, per se, for array types that will perform any copy deeper than the simple pointer copy.  You may find that this works better if instead you try:

```
std::vector<M3DVector3f*> vertices;
M3DVector3f* v = new M3DVector3f;

sscanf_s(line.c_str(), "%*s %f %f %f", &((*v)[0]), &((*v)[1]), &((*v)[2]));

vertices.push_back(v);
```

There may be another, more elegant solution utilizing smart pointers to clean up each entry in the vector when you go to destroy it later.  :-)

Comment: I tried this, however the use of the 'new' gives me this error: cannot convert from 'float *' to 'M3DVector3f (*)'

Answer (score 0):

Clarifying a bit on GMan's response above

The following code also throws the same error as you have got while doing a push_back.

```
typedef float MYBUF[3];

int main(){
   MYBUF m1;

   MYBUF m2(m1);     // Same Error as in OP
}
```

This is exactly what the vector::push_back does with any T. It tries to make a copy (and hence the term copyable) of the input argument and such a copy is not allowed by the C++ language for array types.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how well it will suit you, but you could experiment with some less direct solution, like the following (which compiles without error):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef float M3DVector3f[3];

struct X
{
    X(M3DVector3f& p) { x_[0] = p[0]; x_[1] = p[1]; x_[2] = p[2]; }
    operator M3DVector3f&() { return x_; }
    M3DVector3f x_;
};

int main()
{
    M3DVector3f v = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<X> xs;
    xs.push_back(v);
}
```